# How to extract value corresponding to a date from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this stock market P/E dataframe from which I want to get the data corresponding to a single date. However the following code throws an error.

```
from nsepy import get_index_pe_history
from datetime import date

nifty_pe = get_index_pe_history(symbol="NIFTY",                             
start=date(2011,1,1), end=date(2015,1,10))
print(type(nifty_pe))
print(nifty_pe.loc[nifty_pe["Date"] == "2014-12-12","P/E"].to_numpy())
```

The data nifty_pe looks like this:

```
              P/E   P/B  Div Yield
  Date                              
 2011-01-03  24.57  3.88       1.01
 2011-01-04  24.53  3.87       1.01
 2011-01-05  24.26  3.83       1.03
```

Error which I am getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shyam/venv/DrFinance/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in     pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Comment: what is error log?

Comment: Keyerror: Date...

Comment: Please add the input and output you want

Comment: @Bravo that means `nifty_pe` does not have key `Date`......

Comment: @DonaldWu: It does, have attached the dataframe print result now.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is not column, but index, so need instead compare by date use date in `string`, but before create `DatetimeIndex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) from `python dates` to `pandas timestamps`:

```
nifty_pe.index = pd.to_datetime(nifty_pe.index)

print(nifty_pe.loc["2011-01-03","P/E"])
24.57
```

Comment: I still get KeyError: '2014-12-12', tried with diff dates also.

Comment: @Bravo - So `print(nifty_pe.loc[2011-01-03","P/E"])` not working?

Comment: @Bravo - What is `print (nifty_pe.index)` ?

Comment: Index([2011-01-03, 2011-01-04, 2011-01-05, 2011-01-06, 2011-01-07, 2011-01-10,
       2011-01-11, 2011-01-12, 2011-01-13, 2011-01-14,
       ...
       2014-12-29, 2014-12-30, 2014-12-31, 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-05,
       2015-01-06, 2015-01-07, 2015-01-08, 2015-01-09],
      dtype='object', name='Date', length=999)

Comment: Your second answer compiles, but gives an empty dataframe - same problem as the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Key error is thrown as the dataframe formed using `get_index_pe_history` has set the `Date` column as the index. The index cannot be called as a column name as you are trying in `nifty_pe["Date"]`. You can reset the index and then use the code you wrote as follows

```
nifty_pe = get_index_pe_history(symbol="NIFTY", start=date(2011,1,1), end=date(2015,1,10)).reset_index()
print(type(nifty_pe))
print(nifty_pe.loc[nifty_pe["Date"] == date(2014,12,12),"P/E"].to_numpy())
```

Although the result is an empty dataframe.

Comment: Why is it empty when I have a value corr. to that date?

Comment: @Bravo This might be because the Date column contains values in date format. And you are trying to match with a string "2014-12-12". you can use date(YYYY,MM,DD) instead of the string "2014-12-12". I made an edit to the post too.